Understanding dense subset of $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure $\epsilon>0?$
When asked to find a dense subset of $[0,1]\subset\mathbb{R}$ with Lebesgue measure $\epsilon>0,$ there exist many solutions one may find; however, there is one which I have never understood entirely. Cited from Folland's Real Analysis Modern Techniques and Their Applications (2nd ed.):

(Folland, p. 38) Let $\{r_j\}_1^{\infty}$  be an enumeration of the rational numbers in $[0,1],$ and given $\epsilon>0,$ let $I_j$ be the interval centered at $r_j$ of length $\epsilon 2^{-j}.$ Then the set $U=(0,1)\cap\bigcup_1^{\infty}I_j$ is open and dense in $[0,1],$ but $m(U)\leq\sum_1^{\infty}\epsilon 2^{-j}=\epsilon.$

(Note that $m$ denotes Lebesgue measure here.) Where I'm confused is that if $\{r_j\}_1^{\infty}$ denotes an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1],$ then since $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ is dense in $\subset\mathbb{R},$ should it not follow then that upon having equipped each rational element with a nonempty open interval $I_j$, the union $\bigcup_1^{\infty}I_j$ should cover $[0,1]?$ Hence, $1=m([0,1])\leq m(\bigcup_1^{\infty}I_j)=\epsilon$ creates a contradiction whenever $\epsilon\in(0,1)$?
I am very grateful for any and all help I can get. Thank you very much.

p.s. I must admit that I do fully anticipate that this question has been explained somewhere on this site in the past. However, after having spent thirty minutes searching for such an explanation (and failing in my efforts), I've conceded and decided to pose the question myself. If anybody has a link to an explanation addressing my question, please link it below and I will happily close this question given it does in fact address my question.

Density doesn't implies $[0,1]$ is covered by $\bigcup_i U_i$. For example, let every rational number $q$ is covered by open interval of radius $\lvert q - \sqrt{1/2}\rvert$, it covers $\mathbb{Q}$ but the union doesn't obtains $\sqrt{1/2}\rvert$.

The problem here is open ball of $r$ with radius $d$ doesn't force the points close to $r$ still to have radius $d$.They can have radius smaller and smaller when getting closer to $r$.

@besbeta That makes significantly more sense. I believe my confusion must’ve been in the definition of limit point, though after having re-examined everything, I think I’m good. If you want, you could copy-and-paste this as an answer below, and I’ll mark it as accepted answer? (Plus maybe a small explanation connecting the intuition you introduce to the specific example I provided.)

This is one of those "paradoxes" every student has to struggle with. Once you fix an irrational number $r$ you are tempted to say that for $r_i$'s "close" to $r$, $r$ will lie in the corresponding $U_i$ interval. The problem is that the closeness to $r_i$ does not necessarily match the length of the interval $U_i$; $\ell(U_i)$ can be much smaller than $|r-r_i|$.
